# Physical significance of 3rd derivative

Tags: calculus, soft-question, physics, intuition, applications

I am new to calculus and currently learning differentiation. I understood that the first derivative indicates the slope of the function and the second derivative indicates the rate at which the slope is increasing or decreasing. I have seen some questions asking to find the 3rd derivative of functions and can't understand what would be its geometrical/physical significance. I would appreciate if someone could explain why 3rd derivatives are important. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This quantity is called "jerk". You can think of it as the rate at which acceleration changes. If your function measures position after time $t$, then the first derivative measures speed, the second measures acceleration, and the third measures the rate of change of acceleration.

Comment: For more details and applications see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics)).

Comment: @Sunyata Thanks, I understood

Comment: It may be worth asking on [PSE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions). It may have been asked before, there is even a specific [tag](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jerk).